Web3py and Uniswap issue, transacction reverted
import json
from web3 import Web3

# Set up your connection to Ethereum
infura_url = 'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/apikey'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

if not web3.is_connected():
    raise Exception("Failed to connect to the Ethereum network.")

# Wallet configuration
wallet_address = 'address'
private_key = 'privatekey'

# Contract addresses for Uniswap V3, WETH, and the token
uniswap_router_address = '0x3bFA4769FB09eefC5a80d6E87c3B9C650f7Ae48E'  # Uniswap V3 router address
token_address = '0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984'  # Address of the token you want to obtain
w_eth_address = '0xfff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b14'  # WETH address on Mainnet

# Load the ABI for the ERC20 token contract, WETH, and the Uniswap V3 router
erc20_abi = json.loads('[]')  # ABI of the token (replace with the correct ABI)
uniswap_router_abi = json.loads('[]')  # ABI of the router (replace with the correct ABI)
weth_abi = json.loads('[]')  # ABI of WETH (replace with the correct ABI)

# Convert addresses to checksum format
wallet_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(wallet_address)
uniswap_router_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(uniswap_router_address)
token_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(token_address)
w_eth_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(w_eth_address)

# Create contract instances
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=erc20_abi)
uniswap_router = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_router_address, abi=uniswap_router_abi)
w_eth_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=w_eth_address, abi=weth_abi)

def approve_token(amount):
    # Approve the token spending for Uniswap
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)
    transaction = token_contract.functions.approve(
        uniswap_router_address,
        amount
    ).build_transaction({
        'chainId': 11155111,  
        'gas': 200000,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print(f'Approval transaction sent: {tx_hash.hex()}')
    return tx_hash

def wrap_eth(amount_in_eth):
    # Wrap ETH into WETH
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)
    transaction = w_eth_contract.functions.deposit().build_transaction({
        'chainId': 11155111,  
        'value': web3.to_wei(amount_in_eth, 'ether'),
        'gas': 200000,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print(f'Wrap transaction sent: {tx_hash.hex()}')
    return tx_hash

def swap_exact_input(amount_in, amount_out_min, recipient):
    # Get the nonce for the transaction
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)

    # Create the swap path as bytes
    path = (
        web3.to_checksum_address(w_eth_address).lower().encode('utf-8') + 
        web3.to_checksum_address(token_address).lower().encode('utf-8')
    )

    # Build the transaction for the swap
    transaction = uniswap_router.functions.exactInput(
        (path, recipient, amount_in, amount_out_min)  # Pass all parameters as a single argument
    ).build_transaction({
        'chainId': 11155111,  
        'gas': 200000,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    # Sign the transaction
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
    
    # Send the transaction
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print(f'Swap transaction sent: {tx_hash.hex()}')
    return tx_hash

def main():
    amount_in_eth = float(input("Enter the amount of ETH to swap: "))
    amount_out_min = float(input("Enter the minimum amount of tokens you want to receive: "))
    recipient = wallet_address

    # Check the ETH balance in the wallet
    balance_eth = web3.eth.get_balance(wallet_address)
    if balance_eth < web3.to_wei(amount_in_eth, 'ether'):
        raise Exception("You do not have enough ETH in your wallet.")

    # Wrap ETH to WETH if needed
    print("Wrapping ETH into WETH...")
    wrap_tx_hash = wrap_eth(amount_in_eth)
    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(wrap_tx_hash)

    # Check the WETH balance
    weth_balance = w_eth_contract.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call()
    print(f'WETH balance: {web3.from_wei(weth_balance, "ether")} WETH')

    # Check the necessary amount for the swap
    amount_in_wei = web3.to_wei(amount_in_eth, 'ether')

    # Check the allowance status for the token contract
    allowance = token_contract.functions.allowance(wallet_address, uniswap_router_address).call()

    if allowance < amount_in_wei:
        print("You have not approved the contract to spend this amount. Approving now...")
        approve_tx_hash = approve_token(amount_in_wei)
        web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(approve_tx_hash)

    # Perform the swap of WETH for the token
    print("Performing the swap of WETH for the token...")
    swap_tx_hash = swap_exact_input(amount_in_wei, web3.to_wei(amount_out_min, 'ether'), recipient)
    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(swap_tx_hash)
    print("Swap completed successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


While my code executes and sends transactions, they consistently revert. Here are some potential reasons I suspect:
1 Slippage: Is my amount_out_min value set too low?
2 Gas Limit: Is the gas limit sufficient for the transaction?
3 Is there something else I'm not seeing?
This is one of the transactions generated by the script that end up reverting:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xb0afac74c5bf12cb65dadf9d91da2ce33c4e0b820bdd48a6b97c6c047fd03c2a

You can use Tenderly.co to debug your transaction by hash

Here is also a swap tutorial https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/make-uniswap-v3-swap-in-python.html

The proble with https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/make-uniswap-v3-swap-in-python.html is that uses another libray that only works on ethereum. Im testing with web3py on ethereum sepolia but the idea is to move the script to another blockchain like base or other l2, even bnb or polygon. So i need web3py. But thanks for the info of Tenderly.co

As the author of the library, I can guarantee it works on every EVM. In fact the example is for Polygon if you read it.
